# Cordova 2.3.0 simple setup index.html eclipse android

Tags: javascript, cordova

I downloaded Cordova 2.3.0 to upgrade from Cordova 1.9.0. Before my jQuery mobile page started successfully with the following line and a javascript function.

```
<body onload="onLoad();">
```

Now I see they have an deviceready event. How can I make my application work as before.

Comment: The `deviceready` event was available in 1.9.0. If your app didn't need to use it before it should still work now. Did you properly follow all the upgrade instructions? You might need to post more information (platforms you're testing on, more code, etc.)

Comment: Also double check if your `onLoad()` function is getting executed. You can do so by including a `console.log("message")` in your function and monitoring the log data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running your JavaScript application within the PhoneGap platform, you *may* need to wait until PhoneGap has been completely initialized depending on the functionality that you are going to be using. To properly wait for PhoneGap to initialize, use the below code:

```
var callback = function () {
    // Initialization code goes here. If it's just onLoad(), you can 
    // remove this callback function and just use that instead. 
    onLoad();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", callback, false);
};
```

Hope this helps.